# How to divide a webpage horizontally?

Tags: html

I am learning `HTML`. I was reading the `<div>` tag in a book. I understand how it breaks the website into vertical pieces but I have also seen examples where people use `<div>` tag at the sidebar. How does the `<div>` tag work horizontally?

Comment: Please format HTML tags by wrapping them in backquotes (`).

Comment: Sorry. Was editing it but thanks to Jared. He did it before me :)

Comment: Read on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: Also you might checkout http://thehardsix.com/html/two/inlineblock/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have them so they are side by side, you need to use CSS. A div element by default has the display property set to block. So therefore elements after it will usually appear below.

To setup a couple columns lets say you have the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

You can setup the columns by applying CSS rules to the classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
      width:500px;
    }
    .left {
      width:250px;
      float:left;
    }
    .right {
      width:250px;
      float:right;
    }
</style>
```

In short, im giving it a container to have a maximum width. It's not required, but generally done this way. Then I set both divs to be half the width of the container, and i put float left on it. So all elements will stick beside it. The float right is optional. However, if you make the container wider, the right div will stick on the right hand side.

Comment: I need to remember to use that site sometimes :). Just to add, if you take out the container div, the two middle divs will use the full width. So the right will be on the far right side of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

It is considered a block element and has a width of 100%.

I'd suggest you try it in a text editor & your browser by adding a background-color and some content in it.